# How to calculate average of an Array

Tags: java

```js
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;


public class MyClass 
{
    
        String[] getdata()
        {
            Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter numbers to calculate their average (choose 5 to 10 numbers only : ");
            
            String[] a=in.nextLine().split(" ");
            return a;
        }
        double average(String[] num)
        {
            double avg;
            int tot=0;
            int[] numbers = new int[num.length];
            int l=num.length;
            for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
            {
                tot=tot+numbers[j];
            }
            avg=tot/l;
            return avg;
        }
        void results(String[] arr,double avg)
        {
            int[] numbers1=new int[arr.length];
            int ll=arr.length;
            System.out.print("The average of the numbers ");
            for(int i=0;i<ll;i++)
            {
                numbers1[i]=Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
                System.out.print(numbers1[i]+" ");
                
            }
            System.out.print("is ");
            System.out.printf("%.2f",avg);
        }
        
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        MyClass obj=new MyClass();
        String[] x=obj.getdata();
        double y=obj.average(x);
        obj.results(x,y);
    }
}
```

The code is running successfully but for any given output the average is showing as 0.00.

The code takes in integers with space between them and calculates the average and displays it

Help me fix it. Thanks

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4685450/3788176

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not initialize your `numbers` array inside `average()` method.
Instead of `tot=tot+numbers[j];` do the following

```
tot = tot + Integer.parseInt(num[j]);
```

And to avoid integer deletion change calculation if `avg` to the following

```
avg = 1.0 * tot / l; //this will cast intermediate result of 1.0 * tot to double.
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues with your code:

- The only thing `int[] numbers` shares with `String[] num` input is *length*. All items of the array remain zero, which in itself is sufficient to explain zero result
- Even though `avg` is `double`, `tot/l` is an `int`. It could be truncated down to zero, depending on the values inside `num`.

You need to modify your code to parse `String`s from `num`, and compute `total` as `double`. After that the division would return the correct result.

Further, you can avoid multiple parses of strings if you return `int[]` from `getdata()` method. Given the small number of inputs, this one is not critical for performance of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You never copy the values from `String[] num` to your `int[] numbers`, so when you loop through the whole array `numbers`, you are going to be summing the default value `0`, `l` times.

You need to use `parseInt()` on all the values in `num` to convert it to ints and store them in `numbers`, then make sure you do `float(tot)/l` to cast it to a float during the division. This avoids truncation due to integer division.

Answer (score 0):

In the average method you create an empty array called numbers. You're calculating the average based on that array which is empty.

Hope this helps

Comment: It's not empty, it just contains 0 values.

Answer (score 0):

Your numbers array is wrong in the average function. Please find the corrected code below,

```
double average(String[] num)
        {
            double avg;
            int tot=0;
            int l=num.length;
            for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
            {
                tot=tot+Integer.parseInt(num[j]);
            }
            avg=tot/l;
            return avg;
        }
```

Change the data types as you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend printing `a` from getdata() to ensure that your numbers are getting entered correctly. My best guess is taht something in the split command is not working right.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your average function. You initializes the array of `int[] num`, but you did not write the `int` value in it. You can do that as in the same way as in `void results(String[] arr,double avg)`.

Another problem is, that you get the average `avg = tot/l;` where tot and l are int values. When you divide 2 integer values the result is an `int` too and the `int` value will be written into 'avg'. If the average is a floiting point number (example input "1 2", then the floiting part get cutoff and your programm returns the avg = 1. Therefore the division needs at least one variable, which is double.

This one should work:

```
    double average(String[] num)
    {
        double avg;
        double tot=0;
        int l=num.length;
        for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
        {
            tot=tot+Integer.parseInt(num[j]);
        }
        avg= tot/l;
        return avg;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not initializing the numbers[] array .

```
double average(String[] num)
     {
         double avg;
         double tot=0;
         int[] numbers = new int[num.length];
         for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++)
         {
             numbers[i]=Integer.parseInt(num[i]);
         }
         int l=num.length;
         for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
         {
             tot=tot+numbers[j];
         }
         avg=tot/l;
         return avg;
     }
```

If you are using > Jdk8 . you can use

```
double average(String[] num) {
        OptionalDouble tot = Arrays.stream(num).mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s)).average();
        return tot.orElse(0.0);
    }
```

}